# Python - Find out aspect ratio of image

Tags: python, landscape, aspect-ratio

I'm writing a script that automatically lets me download images from a website and set them as my background. But I only want landscape/horizontal pictures, **is there a way for python to see the aspect ratio of an image** and then discard them based on whether it's horizontal or vertical? And would this be easier to do after downloading the pictures, or before using Selenium?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!, In order for community to help you better, please explain your code in more details and try to put a snippet of code, where you want help.
Assuming that you have used `PIL` to read your image then --> `im = Image.open('whatever.png')
width, height = im.size`
then `aspect_ratio = weight/height`, then you can determine whether it is landscape/portrait

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the Python OpenCV Library, available [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/).
With openCV you can read the width and height of your choice image. Just like this:

`import cv2`

```
im = cv2.imread('www.your_image_url.com')
h, w, c = im.shape
# h is the image height, and w is the width. Note that for portrait images w is always less that h
# then pass your download condition
if w < h:
   # do not download image code
else:
   # download image code
```